# Tick Marks in Geometry

Tags: graphs

Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.5]
    \coordinate[label=left:$A$]  (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[label=right:$B$]  (B) at (1,0);
    \coordinate[label=:$C$]  (C) at (0.5,0.866);
    \draw[] (A)--(B)--(C)--(A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to denote AB=BC using the tick mark notation. Also, point C isn't exactly where it should be. How can I fix that? I rounded sqrt(3)/2 to 0.866.
One last thing: I only want single tick marks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us -- as usual here --an short compilable code resulting in your issue ...

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could include a sketch of how the output should look like.

Comment: Ti*k*Z understands polar coordinates such as `coordinate[label=:$C$]  (C) at (60:1);` It also understands `coordinate[label=:$C$]  (C) at (0.5,{sqrt(3)/2});`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You can add these marks with `decorations.markings`. Since you want two of them, it is shorter to use the `.list` key for that. Further, Ti*k*Z understands polar coordinates, and it also understands `(0.5,{sqrt(3)/2})`, so there is no need to unbury your calculator. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.5,equal mark/.style={postaction={decorate,
decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\draw (-2pt,-4pt) -- (-2pt,4pt);
\draw (2pt,-4pt) -- (2pt,4pt);}}}}]
    \coordinate[label=left:$A$]  (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[label=right:$B$]  (B) at (1,0);
    \coordinate[label=:$C$]  (C) at (60:1);
    \draw[equal mark/.list={1/6,1/2}] (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, this code starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, and is compilable.

And you may simplify/shorten the code using a `\foreach` loop.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.5,equal mark/.style={postaction={decorate,
decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\draw (-2pt,-4pt) -- (-2pt,4pt);
\draw (2pt,-4pt) -- (2pt,4pt);}}}}]
    \foreach \X/\Y in {210/A,-30/B,90/C} 
    {\coordinate[label=\X:$\Y$]  (\Y) at (\X:{1/sqrt(3)});}
    \draw[equal mark/.list={1/6,1/2,5/6}] (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution just for fun purposes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\pspicture[MarkAngle=90](-4,4)
    \pstTriangle(4;150){C}(-4,0){A}(0,0){B}
    \pstSegmentMark{A}{B}
    \pstSegmentMark{B}{C}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Bonus

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {90,100,...,170}{%
\pspicture[MarkAngle=90](-4,4)
    \pstTriangle(4;\i){C}(-4,0){A}(0,0){B}
    \pstSegmentMark{A}{B}
    \pstSegmentMark{B}{C}
\endpspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

one more `tikz` solution. for marks are used math symbol `\|` in nodes with option `sloped` placed on lines:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.141592mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.5]
\coordinate[label=left:$A$]     (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=right:$B$]    (B) at (1,0);
\coordinate[label=$C$]          (C) at (0.5,0.866);
\draw (A) -- node {$\|$} (B) -- node[sloped] {$\|$} (C) -- (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

now `tikz` version 3.1 in `miktex` works ...

[image]

Comment: The mark on BC is not perpendicular I think ( I compile with my heart).

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy, of course not, i forgot  to add option `sloped` ...  i correct this.